# Auto populate text field depending on dropdown using same SQL table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to populate a text field and a text area depending on the choice of the second dropdown list using an SQL table. Somehow I got it all wrong. Here's my code right now:

**AJAX/HTML**

```
<script>
  function getPackage(val) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_package.php",
   data:'serviceid='+val,
   success: function(data){
      $("#package-list").html(data);
       }
    });
   }

   function getPackageDesc(val) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_packagedesc.php",
   data:'packageid='+val,
   success: function(data){
      $("#price").html(data);
      }
    });
   }

   function selectService(val) {
   $("#search-box").val(val);
   $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
     }
</script>
```

I feel like there is already something wrong with function getPackageDesc. I don't know if it's in this function or in the php file.

**MAIN HTML**

```
<div class="frmDronpDown">
 <div class="row">
   <label>Service:</label>
   <br/>
   <select name="service" id="service-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getPackage(this.value);">
     <option value="">Select Service</option>
     <?php
      foreach($results as $service) {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $service[" serviceid "]; ?>">
      <?php echo $service["servicename"]; ?>
     </option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Package:</label>
    <br/>
    <select name="package" id="package-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getPackageDesc(this.value);">
      <option value="">Select Package</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Package Information:</label>
    <br/>
    <br/> Price:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
    <br>
    <br> Package Description:
    <br>
    <textarea name="packagedesc" form="usrform" id="packagedesc"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**get_package.php**

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["serviceid"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_packages WHERE serviceid = '".$_POST["serviceid"]."'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?> < option value = "" > Select Package < /option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $package) {
?> < option value = "<?php echo $package["
packageid "]; ?>" > <?php echo $package["packagename"]; ?> < /option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

This part of the code works. I have populated the dropdowns using two SQL tables, *tbl_services* and *tbl_packages*. The next php file is where I'm having trouble.

**get_packagedesc.php**

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["packageid"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_packages WHERE packageid = '".$_POST["packageid"]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <?php echo $price['price'] ; ?></br>    
    <?php echo $packagedesc['packagedesc']; ?>  </br>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

This code is where I'm having trouble at. I don't know if it is okay to get data from the same SQL table (tbl_packages). Or maybe I messed up with the $result.

What is wrong with my code and what could be the solution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Before posting on Stackoverflow always try to debug the code yourself. It is the best way to learn. Have you tried logging whatever the request returns on the console? Also, always have a fail method on your Ajax to request to know if the request went through at all. Your data element should also be on an object format `{ field : value }`. You should also make sure that your script has access to the post info you sent it. So run a `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: The thing is , I'm a novice on using AJAX. I tried debugging but I don't exactly know where it goes wrong. That's why I asked. As to your suggestion, I don't exactly understand. Can you please elaborate? The reason I posted here is to learn from the people who know more.

Comment: Begin by putting a console.log(data) on all your success function. Then, add a new function called `fail`, I do it differently, but this should work just fine in order to keep your code uniform: Add a new function much like success, except instead of success call it fail, and put another `console.log(data)` on that function. Then, on both of your PHP files, do `var_dump($_POST);`, then open up your console and begin testing. Most output should be seen under the `responseText` element if your request fails. (You get an error on your console)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not grabbing the information from the row itself but from undeclared variables. Try this:

```
<?php echo $row['price'] ; ?></br>    
<?php echo $row['packagedesc']; ?>  </br>
```

Comment: It didn't work Yusef. It was because row is just a div class and is just the container for the values. The container where I would print the fetched data is in the text input and the text area. Thanks though.